# Ruby httpclient url

Tags: ruby, https, httpclient

I am making a call to a webservice via `HTTPClient` ruby gem. The location doesn't matter, but let's say it is at: `https://mywebservice.com/api/v1/accounts/login/`

When I send a post request:

```
url = "https://mywebservice.com/api/v1/accounts/login/"
client = HTTPClient.new
client.post url
```

I get a 404 response, that the page was not found. I setup a proxy and checked out exactly what was being sent it seems like the gem is messing up the url, it actually sends the request to:

```
https://mywebservice.comhttps://mywebservice.com:443/api/v1/accounts/login/
```

I am completely lost, I have no why it is doing that. Does it have anything to do with the fact that it's https and I should handle https differently?
Thanks

Comment: is that a typo or is the request really `https://mywebservice.comhttps://mywebservice.com:443/api/v1/accounts/login/`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are requesting a `https` url do this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse(url)

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
#you need to set this field to true
http.use_ssl = true 
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request(request)
```

Here is a link that should help:

http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/httpclient-is-a-nice-http-client-forin-ruby/

Comment: One thing to note is that you should be very careful with verify_mode. You (probably) want it set to none in development, but it should emphatically be verifying in production.

Comment: I am using HTTPClient gem and using that to interface with the API, not net/http. Can you please tell me what settings I have to change there?

Comment: client.ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Answer (score -3):

You should post to an uri with a body of params. Something like

```
client.post "http://mysite.com:8080", data
```

where data is a hash with the required parameters for the page.

For instance:

```
data = {"var" => "var"}
```